# Is this proof regarding the nonexistence of odd perfect numbers correct?

Tags: solution-verification, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Preamble:  This post is an offshoot of this [earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/382050), which was not so well-received in MathOverflow.

Let $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.  Denote the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

If $m$ is odd and $\sigma(m)=2m$, then $m$ is called an *odd perfect number*.  Euler proved that a hypothetical odd perfect number must necessarily have the form
$$m = q^k n^2$$
where $q$ is the *special/Euler prime* satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

As proved in MO, we have the following equation:
$$I(n^2) - \frac{2(q - 1)}{q} = \frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\cdot{I(n^2)},$$
whereupon, starting from the lower bound
$$I(n^2) > \frac{2(q - 1)}{q}$$
we get the recursive estimates
$$I(n^2) > \frac{2(q - 1)}{q} + \frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\cdot\frac{2(q - 1)}{q}$$
$$I(n^2) > \frac{2(q - 1)}{q} + \frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg(\frac{2(q - 1)}{q} + \frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\cdot\frac{2(q - 1)}{q}\bigg)$$
$$= \frac{2(q - 1)}{q}\cdot\Bigg(1 + \frac{1}{q^{k+1}} + \bigg(\frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg)^2\Bigg)$$
$$I(n^2) > \frac{2(q - 1)}{q} + \frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\Bigg(\frac{2(q - 1)}{q}\cdot\Bigg(1 + \frac{1}{q^{k+1}} + \bigg(\frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg)^2\Bigg)\Bigg)$$
$$= \frac{2(q - 1)}{q}\cdot\Bigg(1 + \frac{1}{q^{k+1}} + \bigg(\frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg)^2 + \bigg(\frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg)^3\Bigg)$$
$$\ldots$$
$$\ldots$$
$$\ldots$$
**Repeating the process ad infinitum, we get:**
$$I(n^2) > \frac{2(q - 1)}{q}\cdot\Bigg(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{\bigg(\frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg)^i}\Bigg).$$
But
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{\bigg(\frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg)^i}$$
is an *infinite geometric series*, with sum
$$\frac{a_0}{1 - r}$$
where the first term $a_0 = 1$ and the common ratio
$$r = \frac{1}{q^{k+1}}.$$
Hence, we obtain
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{\bigg(\frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg)^i} = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{q^{k+1}}},$$
from which we finally get
$$I(n^2) > \frac{2(q - 1)}{q}\cdot\frac{q^{k+1}}{q^{k+1} - 1}.$$

But we can simplify the **RHS** of the last inequality as follows:
$$\frac{2(q - 1)}{q}\cdot\frac{q^{k+1}}{q^{k+1} - 1} = \frac{2q^k (q - 1)}{q^{k+1} - 1} = \frac{2q^k}{\sigma(q^k)} = \frac{2}{I(q^k)} = I(n^2).$$

We have therefore finally arrived at the contradiction
$$I(n^2) > I(n^2).$$

**We therefore conclude that there cannot be any odd perfect numbers.**

Here is my:

> **QUESTION:** Does this proof hold water?  If it does not, where is the error in the argument, and can it be mended so as to produce a valid proof?

Comment: If $I(n^2)$ is greater than all the individual recursive estimates, this does not prove it is greater than the limit of the recursive estimates.

Comment: From the point "As proved in MO" on, you do *not* use at all that $I(n^2)$ is the anything special, i.e., you can replace $I(n^2)$ with $y$ throughout. In other words, you believe to arrive at a contradiction $y>y$ from $y-\frac{2(q-1)}q=\frac1{q^{k+1}}y$, when it is straightforward so solve this equation for $y$.

Comment: @Peter:  I think your point would be debatable, depending on one's point of view regarding limits and infinity.  Hence, my reason for posting the question in the first place.

Comment: @ArnieBebita-Dris There is no debate. $\frac1n>0$ does not imply $0=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n>0$

Comment: I have submitted this comment as an answer.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen:  If one solves
$$y - \frac{2(q - 1)}{q} = \frac{1}{q^{k+1}}y$$
for $y$, then one gets
$$y = \frac{2q^k (q - 1)}{q^{k+1} - 1} = \frac{2q^k}{\sigma(q^k)} = \frac{2}{I(q^k)} = I(n^2),$$
which I am sure you are well-aware that I know of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your statements about the recursive estimates for $I(n^2)$ are correct, $I(n^2)$ may still not be greater than the limit of the recursive estimates. If we know $a>x_n$ for all $n$, and $x_n\to x$ as $n\to\infty$, we can only deduce that $a\ge x$.

Answer (score 0):

In your mathoverflow post, you write
$$\frac{2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)}{\sigma(q^k) - q^k} = \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))$$
because $\gcd(\sigma(q^k), q^k) = 1.$ Why is this true? I do not see any reason it should hold.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @user951252.  Please see [(Lemma 2.1, page 13)](http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-23/NNTDM-23-2-012-020.pdf) in the hyperlinked paper.